# Retrieving of data from sql not working well

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve a boolean where it 1 is true and 0 false, true to represent verified. On my local database i got the code working it returned me 1.

But i need to do convert to a online database, so i did with the same code, but now instead of returning me 1 or 0, it returned me null. Does anyone know why? I compared the codes they are exactly the same but different results. It seems that it can't even retrieve, i have several other phps but all are working fine. Please help

php:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
include_once('db.php');
session_start();

    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `userdetails` WHERE `username` = '".$_SESSION['user']."'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);     
        $verifiedBool = $row["VerifiedBool"];

        if($verifiedBool == 1)
        {
            $result2 = json_encode(
                array("verify"=>"true", "username"=>$_SESSION['user'], "bool"=>$verifiedBool, "bool2"=>$row['VerifiedBool'])
                ); 
                echo $result2;
        }

        else
        {
            $result2 = json_encode(
                array("verify"=>"false", "username"=>$_SESSION['user'], "bool"=>$verifiedBool, "bool2"=>$row['VerifiedBool'])
                ); 
                echo $result2;
        }
    } 

    else {
        $result2 = json_encode(
                array("verify"=>"false", "username"=>$_SESSION['user'], "bool"=>$verifiedBool, "bool2"=>$row['VerifiedBool'])
                ); 
                echo $result2;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you actually add the field to the second db? PHP will return null when the field doesn't actually exist.

Comment: You should use parameterized queries instead of concatenation for security purpose.